# Render can't work with content_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a render:

```
 = render :partial => 'friendship/friends', :collection => @friendships.find_all{|item| item.friend.friends.include?(current_user)}
```

The render code is:

```
= content_tag_for(:tr,friendship) do
  %td
    =link_to friendship.friend do
      .post_image.fl_l
        =image_tag friendship.friend.avatar.url(:thumb)
      =friendship.friend.name
      =friendship.friend.surname
    %br
      =link_to "remove",friendship,:method => :delete
```

It outputs this error:

```
> undefined local variable or method `friendship' for
> #<#<Class:0x5ce61b8>:0x5ce35c0>
```

In my controller action I have

```
 @friendships = current_user.friendships
    @users_friended =current_user.inverse_friends
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
```

I was doing the same with message

```
 = render :partial => 'messages/message', :collection => @messages_received
```

The render code had

```
= content_tag_for(:tr,message) do
....
```

the controller action had

```
 @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @messages_received=@user.received_messages.reverse
    @messages_sent=@user.sent_messages.reverse
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
```

and it worked fine. I think that I was doing the same, but it doesn't work. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: sorry, my fault, i thought that content_tag second parameter is an object of array of render :collection, it is not right

Comment: if this solves your problem you should post an answer yourself and accept it